# Is there a way to determine what the sum of x to the power m (from 1 to n) evaluates to?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, summation

I know that: $\sum_{x=1}^n x= n(n+1)/2$ but is there a way to generalize that to any power of $x$?

In other words, is there a way to determine what $\sum_{x=1}^n x^m$ is equal to for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$? Is there a clean formula for values where $x\lt1$?

I know I can find the sum of squares and cubes pretty easily but I'm having a hard time finding a general formula.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. 
 You mean [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)?

Comment: What do you mean a clean formula for $x<1$? In your notation, $x$ is a dummy summation variable.

Comment: @Hamed I meant the starting value starts at less than 1. I know we can just calculate each value less than 1 and just add it to the result of numbers > 1, but I was wondering if there was a formula in terms of n

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) gives the sum of the $m$th powers of the first $n$ natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula uses something called Bernoulli number

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html

https://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/bernoulli.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the final formula is related to Bernoulli numbers. But if are not familiar with them, you can still find these formulas with a bit of calculation recursively.

Let's denote $S_n^m = \sum_{k=1}^n k^m$, with $S^0_n := n$. The basic idea is the identity
$$
(k+1)^{m+1}-k^{m+1} = \sum_{\ell=0}^{m} \binom{m+1}{\ell} k^{\ell}
$$
By doing a sum over $k$, we find
$$
(n+1)^{m+1}-1 = 
\sum_{\ell=0}^{m} \binom{m+1}{\ell} S^\ell_n
$$

---

For example,

- $m=1$: Since $S^0_n=n$
  $$
  (n+1)^2-1 = n + 2S_n^1\Longrightarrow \boxed{S_n^1= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}}
  $$
- $m=2$,
  $$
  (n+1)^3-1 = n + 3S_{n}^1 + 3S_{n}^2\Longrightarrow \boxed{S_n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}
  $$
  and so on...